# How do I delete a command button using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that contains a command button named "update".

How can I delete this button using VBA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it :

```
For Each o In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes      

   If o.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "update" Then
        o.Delete
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Had the same problem and tried your code, gave me a "this member cannot be accessed on a horizontal line" error, any idea on what's going wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think when you said 'Button Name' you ment 'Button Caption'; please try below code -

```
For Each o In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
   If o.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "update" Then
        o.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Regards,
Nilesh

PS: the caption is case sensitive, so you may want to check the case for caption.