# Word Macro: "Sub or function not defined" on 2nd PC

Tags: vba, ms-word, undefined

I created a .docm file with 2 macros and everything works fine on my PC but if I copy the .docm file to a different PC, it displays a "sub or function not defined" error.

Macro 1:
An activeX button (`Developer - Legacy tools`) with a macro attached to it:

```
Private Sub buttonStart_Click()
    Main
End Sub
```

Macro 2: "Main" (created via `View - Macros - Show Macros`)

```
Sub Main()
    'Calls other subs and functions in the right order
End Sub
```

On the other PC I gave Word permission to use activeX but the "Main" macro is missing in the `View - View Macros` list and it's displaying the error message every time I try to start the macro(s) by clicking the button.

Sorry, I'm new to VBA and macros. Do I have to link the second macro or add it in a different way to be accessible on other PCs?

Edit: The left side in the VBA editor (looks the same for both macros):

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the macros contained in the document in the VBA Editor? The default location where Word will save a "new macro" is the Normal.dotm template, not the active document. Start Word, open the document, go to the VBA editor. On the left of the editor window will be a list of the available projects. One will be Normal, one will be the opened document. Open the "Modules" folder for Normal and you should see something like "new macros": Do you find `Sub Main` there?

Comment: I added a screenshots in the first post - both macros look the same on the left but there's only "NewMacros", nothing else. The only difference is: The button macro is missing in the "View - Show macros" list, while the "Main" one is there and if I press Alt + F11, it opens the macro I used last in the VBA editor (but it never has two in the list to switch between them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the situation:

1. When an ActiveX control is double-clicked a procedure will be created (or selected, if it already exists) for the default action of the control. This will always be in the `ThisDocument` class module of the document in which the ActiveX control is embedded.
2. When a macro is created using a control in the Word user interface, that macro will be automatically created in the `Normal.dotm` (default) template, in a module named `NewMacros`.
3. Only macros in normal modules, defined as "public" `Sub` procedures that take no arguments will appear in the available macros list. The reason the event for the ActiveX control does not appear in the list is because a) it's `Private` not public and b) it's not in a normal module - it's in `ThisDocument` which is a class module (represents the document at the code level).

So, `buttonStart_Click` is in the document that's been distributed to another PC, in the `ThisDocument` module. `Sub Main`, on the other hand, was created in `NewMacros` in the Normal.dotm template, which stayed on the original machine.

Therefore, you need to

1. Click on the project `BilderEinlesen`, go to the `Insert` menu and insert a **Module** to the project. By default it will be named `Module1`.
2. Double-click `NewMacros` in the Normal project to open the code page. Select `Sub Main` in its entirety, copy it.
3. Double-click on `Module1` to open the code page. If `Option Explicit` is not at the top, type that in. Paste the copied `Sub Main`.

Now both procedures should be in the document that will be distributed.

Note: Personally, I would rename `Sub Main` to something else. `Sub Main` is genereated by VBA under certain, automated circumstances (such as that used to create this one) and *could* lead to a conflict if VBA again wants to create such a macro... OR if another macro with that name is present in a project opened at the same time. If you do rename, remember to also change the procedure call in the button click event.

Comment: Ah, double-clicking "This Document" in "Project - Microsoft Word Objects" opens the button's macro and "NewMacros" in "Project - Module" should open my normal "Main" macro, which might be in the project already (or not). Thanks for the explanation, I'm going to try your suggestion. In the meantime I also tried something else: In the `View - View Macros` popup there's a button "Organize", which let me copy the "NewMacros" module from Normal.dotm to my .docm file. It didn't create any new modules but afterwards the macros worked on the 2nd PC. Is this the same thing you suggested? Okay - done.

Comment: Yes, the Organizer is another way to copy *public subs* without parameters from one project to another. It won't pick up other things, for the same reasons as mentioned before, as I recall, however @Neph. Which is probably why it doesn't occur to me to use it, anymore :-)

Comment: Good to know then, thanks! I've got one last question: There are multiple subs and a single function in my "Main" macro, two of them take arguments but none of them is private. And yet one of the non-special ones shows up in the "View Macros" window (above the "Main" macro) and I don't know why. It's just [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755476/2016165) code (in a `Sub DeleteButton()`) that deletes my ActiveX button after clicking on it.

Comment: @Neph I'm afraid it's not clear what you have, where it is and what's / is not showing up in the list. Might be better to create a new question, where you can add more details (the code) and screen shots of what you see?

Comment: `View - View Macros` displays a list of the macro files in a Word document. In my case it used to only display the "Main" macro (not the button macro because it's private) but as soon as I added the linked sub to my "Main" macro, that sub showed up in the list too. None of the other subs in the main file do, even though they aren't private or otherwise hidden. If I delete the sub in the list, it also gets deleted in the file. I was just wondering why it would do that but it doesn't seem to actually affect anything in a bad way, so I can live with it - no worries. ;) Thanks again for your help!